# 2 Players combinational game

Tags: python

There's a game I need to write a python code about. I don't know the games' name so I couldn't google it properly.
The function gets destination number ("n") and move_options(list of positive numbers, 1 must be included in it).
Game rules: each player in his move can reduce from "n" any number exists in the move_options. The chosen number is still available in the next turn (list stays the same).
The player that changes "n" to 0 wins (n can't be negative).
The function returns a bool value - True if in given n and move_options current player can win, and False if not.

I know it's a recursion question, but I don't understand how to consider other player's move.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the name of the game if you are supposed to "write a python code about it"? Surely, you are not trying to cheat by finding an existing solution? (Assuming this is homework.)

Comment: I have a test in python tomorrow. Saw this question in an old test and there was no answer attached. Tried solving in myself but didn't manage to get an answer that covers all posibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I would start this problem by considering some base cases:

```
def current_player_win(dest, move_options):
    if dest in move_options:
        return True
```

This is the obvious "if I am one move away from winning, I win! case. For completeness, I'd also add this:

```
def current_player_win(dest, move_options):
    if dest in move_options:
        return True
    if dest == 0:
        # Other player must have moved to 0. They won.
        return False
```

Now, as you say, the guts of the problem: what to do with the other player's turn.

Well, now you need to consider every possible move:

```
def current_player_win(dest, move_options):
    if dest in move_options:
        return True
    if dest == 0:
        # Other player must have moved to 0. They won.
        return False
    for my_move in move_options:
        if my_move < dest:
            other_wins_if_i_do_this = current_player_win(dest - my_move, move_options)
            # Now do something with other_wins_if_i_do_this
```

So by calling the function recursively, you now have a variable that is `True` if the *other* player wins after the current player makes the move `my_move`, and it's `False` if the other player loses after the current player makes `my_move`.

So what should you do with that? Obviously, if `other_wins_if_i_do_this` gives the same value for every move, you'd return the opposite. But what if `other_wins_if_i_do_this` is `True` for some values, but `False` for others? What would you want your player to do then?

Comment: This would work, in theory, but in reality the complexity would probably explode for larger inputs, as many states (number of remaining items) is checked again and again on countless recursive paths. This should at least use some form of memoization, or dynamic programming. (I'm aware that this is not supposed to be a full solution, but I think this kind of hint is still important.)

Comment: Thats exactly what i thought! The main missing thing is the case where every move of the other player will lead to me losing. I can return the opposite of the other player's value, but it won't indicate anything about the rest of the cases.

Comment: Yes, after filling in the rest of the logic there so that the correct answer is reached, the next step is to use some simple form of memoization. Make it right, then make it fast.

That being said, in the form that I played this game as a child (dest=20 or 30 and move_options either `[1,2]` or `[1,2,3]`) the answer returns fast enough to do some checking of the logic.

Comment: @L.Kiwi - you aren't considering every possible move of the other player (directly). You're just considering "will the other player win if I make this move". You assume that the other player knows as much about the game as you do, and will make the best possible move for them. Therefore, if there's any move where `other_wins_if_i_do_this` returns False, you know that when you make that move, you win, and you can return True. If there's no such move (if the other wins no matter what you do), then return False.

Answer (score 0):

For specific cases this one works, but I believe it doesn't alway work. What do you think?

```
def current_player_win(dest, move_options):
    if num<0: return False
    if num in move_options:
        return True
    for move in move_options:
        if current_player_win(num-move, move_options) == True:
            return False
            break
    return True
```

Comment: 1) That won't work because you've confused `num` and `dest`.
2) That `break` statement is pointless, and will never be reached.
3) Instead of returning `False` if a recursive call returns `True`, try returning `True` if a recursive call returns `False`.

Comment: The idea is that you can ignore the other moves if you've found a way to move so that the other player loses, because if you've found some move that lets you win you'll just do that. If you've found a move so that the other player wins if you take it, then you need to keep looking if you can.